# Assign different values to a reg multiple times in an initial block

Tags: verilog, simulation

```
module dff (clk, reset,
  d, q, qb);
  input      clk;
  input      reset;
  input      d;
  output     q;
  output     qb;

  reg        q;

  assign qb = ~q;

  always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
  begin
    if (reset) begin
      // Asynchronous reset when reset goes high
      q <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
      // Assign D to Q on positive clock edge
      q <= d;
    end
  end
endmodule


// Code your testbench here
// or browse Examples
module TB;
  
  reg clk;
  reg reset;
  reg d;
  wire q, qb;
  
  dff dff_inst(clk, reset, d, q, qb);
  
  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    reset = 0;
    d = 1;
    
    #1; reset = 1;
    
    #1; reset = 0;
    
    #1;   //// NOTE!!!!!!!!!!
    clk = 0;
    clk = 1;
    clk = 0;
    
    #1;
    $display("q = %b", q);
  end
  
endmodule
```

I'm new to VCS. There is a case, I want to test event-driven algorithm, so at 3 time-slot, I assign 0-1-0 to the `clk` signal in an `initial` block. According to event-driven algorithm, there exists a rise event at `clk`, so I think it will trigger the `always` block, and the `q` will be assigned to 1.  But the `$display` outputs 0 not 1.  Why?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is reasonable behavior by the simulator.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.3.1 *Sequential blocks*:

```
A sequential block shall have the following characteristics:
— Statements shall be executed in sequence, one after another.
```

Since all blocking assignments to `clk` occur in the same time step, the 3rd assignment overrides the others.

If you want a positive edge of `clk`, you should use delays.  It is always best to avoid zero-time glitches.